# App Crashing with NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to add annotations to a map view. Each annotation represents a tweet. I am getting the coordinates for each tweet from the twitter api. The app is crashing right after loading the map. and I'm not sure why.

EDIT: Here is the current version of the relevant code. It runs fine until it comes to a tweet where tweetLocation is null. Then it crashes.

```
STTwitterAPI *twitter = [STTwitterAPI twitterAPIAppOnlyWithConsumerKey:@"key" consumerSecret:@"secret"];

    [twitter verifyCredentialsWithSuccessBlock:^(NSString *username) {

        [twitter getSearchTweetsWithQuery:@"apple" geocode:geoCode lang:nil locale:nil resultType:@"recent" count:@"10" until:nil sinceID:nil maxID:nil includeEntities:nil callback:nil successBlock:^(NSDictionary *searchMetadata, NSArray *statuses) {

            tweetsArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:statuses];
            NSLog(@"tweetsArray: %@", tweetsArray);

            for (int i = 0; i < [tweetsArray count]; i++) {
                NSDictionary *t = tweetsArray[i];
                tweetAnnotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc]init];

                NSArray *tweetLocation = [[t valueForKey:@"geo"]valueForKey:@"coordinates"];
                NSLog(@"Tweet Location: %@", tweetLocation);

                if ([tweetLocation count] == 0) {
                    continue;
                }
                else {
                    double lat = [[tweetLocation objectAtIndex:0]doubleValue];
                    double longitude = [[tweetLocation objectAtIndex:1]doubleValue];
                    locationCoord.latitude = lat;
                    locationCoord.longitude = longitude;

                    twitterName = [t valueForKeyPath:@"user.screen_name"];
                    NSLog(@"Twitter name: %@", twitterName);
                    tweetAnnotation.title = twitterName;

                    tweetAnnotation.coordinate = locationCoord;
                    [tweetLocationsArray addObject:tweetAnnotation];
                }
            }

            [tweetMap addAnnotations:tweetLocationsArray];

        } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {

            NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);

        }];

    } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);

    }];
```

EDIT: Here is current error in the console:

```
2014-10-07 08:00:36.278 Tweets By Location[5244:382886] Tweet Location: (
    "37.33158914",
    "-122.03076495"
)
2014-10-07 08:00:36.278 Tweets By Location[5244:382886] Twitter name: tofuhunter
2014-10-07 08:00:36.278 Tweets By Location[5244:382886] Tweet Location: (
    "37.33161957",
    "-122.03080173"
)
2014-10-07 08:00:36.278 Tweets By Location[5244:382886] Twitter name: treynesss
2014-10-07 08:00:36.278 Tweets By Location[5244:382886] Tweet Location: (
    "37.33161957",
    "-122.03080173"
)
2014-10-07 08:00:36.279 Tweets By Location[5244:382886] Twitter name: mattlarowe
2014-10-07 08:00:36.279 Tweets By Location[5244:382886] Tweet Location: <null>
2014-10-07 08:00:36.279 Tweets By Location[5244:382886] -[NSNull count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10b0accb0
2014-10-07 08:00:36.281 Tweets By Location[5244:382886] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10b0accb0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ae043f5 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010aa9dbb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ae0b50d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ad637fc ___forwarding___ + 988
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ad63398 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   Tweets By Location                  0x000000010a08876e __32-[MapViewController viewDidLoad]_block_invoke_2 + 542
    6   Tweets By Location                  0x000000010a029feb __147-[STTwitterAPI getSearchTweetsWithQuery:geocode:lang:locale:resultType:count:until:sinceID:maxID:includeEntities:callback:successBlock:errorBlock:]_block_invoke + 203
    7   Tweets By Location                  0x000000010a01cd1a __99-[STTwitterAPI getResource:baseURLString:parameters:downloadProgressBlock:successBlock:errorBlock:]_block_invoke117 + 186
    8   Tweets By Location                  0x000000010a0751d8 __95-[STTwitterAppOnly getResource:baseURLString:parameters:progressBlock:successBlock:errorBlock:]_block_invoke104 + 184
    9   Tweets By Location                  0x000000010a065a32 __158+[STHTTPRequest(STTwitter) twitterRequestWithURLString:stTwitterUploadProgressBlock:stTwitterDownloadProgressBlock:stTwitterSuccessBlock:stTwitterErrorBlock:]_block_invoke33 + 722
    10  Tweets By Location                  0x000000010a071538 -[STHTTPRequest connectionDidFinishLoading:] + 472
    11  CFNetwork                           0x00000001105212cc __65-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke + 69
    12  CFNetwork                           0x0000000110521270 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:] + 199
    13  CFNetwork                           0x00000001105213d7 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withActiveConnectionAndDelegate:] + 48
    14  CFNetwork                           0x00000001103f25f7 ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic26_delegate_didFinishLoadingEU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke + 107
    15  CFNetwork                           0x00000001104be871 ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic18_withDelegateAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvP16_CFURLConnectionPK33CFURLConnectionClientCurrent_VMaxE_block_invoke_2 + 273
    16  CFNetwork                           0x00000001103ddb36 _ZN19RunloopBlockContext13_invoke_blockEPKvPv + 72
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ad0c714 CFArrayApplyFunction + 68
    18  CFNetwork                           0x00000001103dd9f7 _ZN19RunloopBlockContext7performEv + 133
    19  CFNetwork                           0x00000001103dd836 _ZN17MultiplexerSource7performEv + 256
    20  CFNetwork                           0x00000001103dd64c _ZN17MultiplexerSource8_performEPv + 72
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ad39ad1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ad2f99d __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ad2efd4 __CFRunLoopRun + 868
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ad2ea06 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    25  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010cf2f9f0 GSEventRunModal + 161
    26  UIKit                               0x000000010b277550 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    27  Tweets By Location                  0x000000010a089e43 main + 115
    28  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010cb78145 start + 1
    29  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Please post the symbolicated stack trace and the complete error message.

Comment: See http://raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: Did you import `MapKit` library?

Comment: @S1LENTWARRIOR, Yes, MapKit is imported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element `"coordinates"` is not a string.

According to the documentation, the objects you are traversing are Tweet objects:
https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/tweets

The `coordinates` portion of this appears similar to this example:

```
  "coordinates":
  [
    -75.14310264,
    40.05701649
  ]
```

You should be parsing `coordinates` as an array representing a (longitude, latitude) pair.

Please note that `coordinates` may be null (compare to `[NSNull null]`), so you should account for that as well.

Comment: How can I get the double values for each of those elements so I can set latitude and longitude?

Comment: They should be stored as NSNumber objects in the NSArray. Use `[longitude doubleValue]` to get the double value.

Comment: I fixed that issue but now it is not getting the tweets for some reason. I was at least getting those before fixing the crashing issue.

Comment: When you say you're not getting tweets, does that mean it doesn't go through the loop for even one iteration? If that's true, how do you know you fixed the crash?

You should check to make sure you didn't exceed your rate limit.

Comment: It is working until the loop comes across null coordinates. See my updated code in my post.

Comment: You're going to need to compare it against [NSNull null].

Answer (score 1):

This line from the crash log:

```
2014-10-06 14:18:08.622 Tweets By Location[3612:174001] -[__NSCFArray length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa983d03510
```

Means that you're sending `length` to an array, but array doesn't have a method called `length`.

The reason is this code:

```
NSString *tweetLocation = [[t valueForKey:@"geo"]valueForKey:@"coordinates"];
NSLog(@"Tweet Location: %@", tweetLocation);

if ([tweetLocation length] == 0) {
    continue;
}
```

You are assuming that whatever's at `geo.coordinates` is a string, but the server is returning an array.

To fix it, look at the spec for what the server should be returning, and adapt your code to match the spec. If the server may return either an array or a string for that field, you can test which was returned at runtime using `isKindOfClass:`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why it was crashing. I had to check if the coordinates JSON array was equal to NSNull.

```
if ([tweetLocation isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {
                    continue;
                }
                else {
                    double lat = [[tweetLocation objectAtIndex:0]doubleValue];
                    double longitude = [[tweetLocation objectAtIndex:1]doubleValue];
                    locationCoord.latitude = lat;
                    locationCoord.longitude = longitude;
                    NSLog(@"Lat: %.8f, Long: %.8f", lat, longitude);

                    twitterName = [t valueForKeyPath:@"user.screen_name"];
                    NSLog(@"Twitter name: %@", twitterName);
                    tweetAnnotation.title = twitterName;

                    tweetAnnotation.coordinate = locationCoord;
                    [tweetLocationsArray addObject:tweetAnnotation];
                }
```